# Remove blank page between Acknowledgements and Table of Contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, numbering, theorems

I get a blank page between “Acknowledgement” and “Table of contents”. How can I remove it? I used a template from somewhere. The preamble is as follows:

```
\documentclass[openany,12pt]{ubthesis}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{srcltx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color, soul}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[subfigure]{graphfig}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} 
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{color} 
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} 
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\input{gams.tex}%newly added 0803

\pagestyle{plain}
\setulcolor{red}
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
\def\bibfont{\small}
\def\bibsep{\smallskipamount}
\def\bibhang{24pt}
\def\newblock{\ }
\def\BIBand{and}

\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\raggedbottom

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{theorem}}  
\newtheorem{acknowledgment}[theorem]{Acknowledgment}
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{case}[theorem]{Case}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Conclusion}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\renewcommand{\thecorollary}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{corollary}}
\newtheorem{criterion}[theorem]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{solution}[theorem]{Solution}
\newtheorem{summary}[theorem]{Summary}
\renewenvironment{proof}{\bf Proof:}{}
```

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)- you shouldn't need all the theorem and bibtex stuff. Please also point us to where we can find `ubthesis.cls`

Comment: Avoid loading `srcltx` and `epsfig` that are obsolete; also `subfigure` is obsolete and `subfig` (or `subcaption`) is to be preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided that `ubthesis.cls` is the document class of the University of Buffalo, downloadable at http://gitorious.org/ubthesis/mainline/trees/master/latex, this is a document class based on the standard `book` class.

So it is loaded with the option `openright` as predefined, i.e. sectioning commands like `\chapter` can only start in odd pages. Moreover, many commands are redefined so to add `\cleardoublepage` in every case.

Having a look at `ubthesis.cls` you can note that the environment `acknowledgements` is defined as:

```
\renewenvironment{acknowledgements}
{
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\markboth
{\MakeUppercase{Acknowledgements}}
{\MakeUppercase{Acknowledgements}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
}
{
\cleardoublepage
}
```

Having said this, the easiest way to remove the blank page between Acknowledgement and Table of Contents is the following:

1. Add this before `\begin{acknowledgements}`:

   ```
   \let\savecleardoublepage\cleardoublepage
   \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
   ```
2. Add this after `\tableofcontents`

   ```
   \let\cleardoublepage\savecleardoublepage
   ```

In this way we change the meaning of `\cleardoublepage` before the Acknowledgements and restore it after the Table of Contents.

The following MWE is a modified version (which does what you want) of the file `thesis.tex` generated from `ubthesis` sources:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{ubthesis}

\title{My Title}

\author{My Name}

\conferral{\today}

\dept{redundancy}

\degree{phd}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\begin{ubfrontmatter}
\makecopyright
\cleardoublepage

\let\savecleardoublepage\cleardoublepage        % save the meaning of \cleardoublepage
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage                  % let \cleardoublepage act as \clearpage

\begin{acknowledgements}
These are my acknowledgements
\end{acknowledgements}

\tableofcontents

\let\cleardoublepage\savecleardoublepage        % restore the meaning of \cleardoublepage

\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\listoftables
\cleardoublepage
\begin{abstract}
This is my abstract
\end{abstract}
\end{ubfrontmatter}

\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{ubbackmatter}
\references[Bibliography]{}
\end{ubbackmatter}

\end{document}
```

### Remarks

1. I suggest not to modify the original behavior since this is a thesis template and probably the University of Buffalo wants you to use it the way they've written it.
2. Just in case you insist on modifying the original behavior: it is not a good practice changing this kind of things for a single page. Probably it is better to modify the behavior for the whole document by putting

   ```
   \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
   ```

   in the preamble or, if you don't mind having a one-sided document, load `ubthesis.cls` with the option `oneside`:

   ```
   \documentclass[10pt,oneside]{ubthesis}
   ```

Note that, in this case, loading `ubthesis.cls` with the option `openany`

```
\documentclass[10pt,openany]{ubthesis}
```

is not enough, since a lot of commands are redefined in the class file so to add `\cleardoublepage` at their end.