# Insertion of a single blank page

Tags: page-breaking

I am trying to finish my thesis which will be printed two sided.

Here is the core of my latex document:

```
\begin{document}
\include{garde}
\frontmatter
\selectlanguage{french}
\include{remerciements}
\selectlanguage{english}
\include{introduction}
\mainmatter
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
...
\end{document}
```

The problem I have is the fact that the title page (named "garde") and the acknowledgments (named "remerciements") are on the same page. Thus I would like to insert a single page to be the back of the title page. But all the attempts I have made, based on \newpage or other related commands have as result the addition of two pages. Thus the "remerciements" and the introduction begin both on a back page.

Could you provide me help on that topic ? Thanks

Comment: I've answered a similar question a few minutes ago... See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128332/27635

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: I am sorry, but your "reply" is actually not an answer but a comment, and I didn't know it was possible to upvote a comment. My mistake is now repaired. Thanks again.

Comment: You can always upvote the answer of mine that lead you to the solution, that's what I meant. Anyway, it's up to you ;-) Happy you've solved.

Comment: That's what I did. I've upvoted your first answer. ;-)

Comment: Probably when you did it, you didn't have enough reputation, but it's OK.

Comment: @karlkoeller This question seems to be answered but still appears in the unanswered list... Should you write an answer to this question?

Comment: @LudovicC. Without knowing the document class and the contents of `\input`ed files, the answer can not be accurate... If Ludo adds some more info, it can be done (or closed as duplicate).